How do i update cfn-response module in CloudFormation stack
I am deploying my Lambda function and getting the below error , I tried to rollback the CloudFromation stack but still getting the same issue .
"CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource.If you are using the Python cfn-response module, you may need to update your Lambda function code so that CloudFormation can attach the updated version"
However I have 2 separate environments in Lambda , one is "test" and the other one is "main" where the test Lambda is working fine in updating the stack(maybe it should have latest stack version since created in 2024 ) but when I deploy the same code in "main" lambda I am getting stuck in above error(maybe the stack was created in 2023 ?) .
I do not use cfn-response module anywhere in my code . The only option left is to update the CloudFormation stack but not sure how .

"CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource" All cloudformation knows is that it invoked the lambda, but nothing posted  the result (success / failure ) to the expected response endpoint.  So you should start your investigation with the lambda logs.  Your solution here is likely to be changing the lambda to adjust for whatever error case is popping up.  Pro tip: lots of folks deploy custom resource lambdas scoped to a particular stack as a resource in the stack so they can iterate on the lambdas along with the stack

Yeah I am trying to deploy a custom S3 resource,and found out that is causing the issue.But the same custom S3 trigger is working fine in the test environment.When I try to test the custom trigger lambda function manually , I am getting the below error :
undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/utils.js\n- /var/task/s3/lib/permissions.js\n- /var/task/s3/handler.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":
INIT_REPORT Phase: invoke Status: errorError Type: Runtime.ImportModuleError

You listed the error in your comment:

ERROR Uncaught Exception
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot
find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/utils.js\n-
/var/task/s3/lib/permissions.js\n- /var/task/s3/handler.js\n-
/var/runtime/index.mjs","stack": INIT_REPORT Phase: invoke Status:
errorError Type: Runtime.ImportModuleError

So your lambda in "main" isn't finding the module that the lambda in "test" is finding.  My guess is that either

The lambdas are not using the same code
The working lambda is referencing a lambda layer that contains the module whereas the broken one lacks the lambda layer reference
The lambdas are configured with different runtimes

So eliminate CloudFormation as a variable--it is a symptom, but the root problem is with Lambda.  Run a test (from the Lambda console) directly on your non-working lambda function to isolate and troubleshoot.

Finally fixed the issue , the runtime was different for the test and main custom created lambda function . The node.js 20.x version did not have aws-sdk installed in it wheres node.js 16.x did ( in test) . But my question is , if I use the same code for both the environment how is the runtime getting mismatched .

It is possible someone altered things after deployment via CloudFormation,  You could run drift detection on the CloudFormation stack to see if that is the case, since any changed items would show as drifted.
